# Is $\tan^{-1}\tan^{-1}1$ irrational?

Tags: trigonometry, reference-request, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

- [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1647390/is-arctan2-irrational), it is proven that $\arctan(2)$ is irrational.
- [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860697/show-that-arctann-is-irrational-for-all-n-in-mathbbn), it is proven that $\arctan(x)$ is irrational for natural $x$. By a proof similar to that from the last linked post, it can easily be shown that $\arctan \frac 1x$ is irrational for natural $x$.
- [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36272/when-is-arctan-a-rational-multiple-of-pi), it is proven that $\arctan(x)$ is a rational multiple of $\pi$ iff $(1+xi)^n$ is a real number for some positive integer $n$.

With these in mind,

> I am wondering if $\tan^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(1))$ is irrational.

It probably is, but I have yet to prove it. We can write $\tan^{-1}1$ as $\frac{\pi}4$ which follows from the fact that $(1+i)^4 = -4$, but I am not sure how to use this information further. I suspect the proof of this is unreachable, though MSE [has surprised me in the past](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1). With this in mind, I have a few related questions, in order of how unlikely they are to be answered:

1. Is $\tan^{-1}\tan^{-1}1$ transcendental?
2. Is $\tan^{-1}\tan^{-1}1$ irrational?
3. Is there any literature on whether $\tan^{-1}\tan^{-1}1$  or a related evaluation of $\arctan$ is irrational/transcendental?
4. Are there any open conjectures which, if true, the irrationality/transcendentality of $\tan^{-1}\tan^{-1}1$  would follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Almost certainly yes.
2. Almost certainly yes.
3. I doubt it.
4. Schanuel's conjecture, I think.